# Conversion to TensorFlow Lite from keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, windows-10, tensorflow-lite

here a beginer as you´ll see :)
I´m trying to convert my trained model in keras (.h5) to TensorFlow Lite format but I´m having the follow error;

AttributeError: type object 'TFLiteConverter' has no attribute 'from_keras_model'

#### The initial code here;

```
    import os
    import sys
    import argparse
    import warnings
    
    def get_parent_dir(n=1):
        """returns the n-th parent dicrectory of the current
        working directory"""
        current_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        for _ in range(n):
            current_path = os.path.dirname(current_path)
        return current_path 

   src_path = os.path.join(get_parent_dir(0), "src")
   sys.path.append(src_path)

   utils_path = os.path.join(get_parent_dir(1), "Utils")
   sys.path.append(utils_path)
```

#### Import libraries;

```
   import numpy as np
   import keras.backend as K
   from keras.layers import Input, Lambda
   from keras.models import Model
   from keras.optimizers import Adam

   from keras.callbacks import (
     TensorBoard,
     ModelCheckpoint,
     ReduceLROnPlateau,
     EarlyStopping,
   )
   from keras_yolo3.yolo3.model import (
     preprocess_true_boxes,
     yolo_body,
     tiny_yolo_body,
     yolo_loss,
   )
   from keras_yolo3.yolo3.utils import get_random_data
   from PIL import Image
   from time import time
   import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
   import pickle

   from Train_Utils import (
     get_classes,
     get_anchors,
     create_model,
     create_tiny_model,
     data_generator,
     data_generator_wrapper,
     ChangeToOtherMachine,
   )
```

#### GPU Config

```
 gpu = tf.config.list_physical_devices("GPU")
       tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu[0], True)

       keras_path = os.path.join(src_path, "keras_yolo3")
       Data_Folder = os.path.join(get_parent_dir(1), "Data")
       Image_Folder = os.path.join(Data_Folder, "Source_Images", "Training_Images")
       VoTT_Folder = os.path.join(Image_Folder, "vott-csv-export")
       YOLO_filename = os.path.join(VoTT_Folder, "data_train.txt")

       Model_Folder = os.path.join(Data_Folder, "Model_Weights")
       YOLO_classname = os.path.join(Model_Folder, "data_classes.txt")

       log_dir = Model_Folder
       anchors_path = os.path.join(keras_path, "model_data", "yolo_anchors.txt")
       weights_path = os.path.join(keras_path, "yolo.h5")
```

#### And the final part with TFLite function converter;

```
 # Convert the model.
    converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
    tflite_model = converter.convert()

    # Save the model.
    with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(tflite_model)

model.save_weights(os.path.join(log_dir, "trained_weights_final.h5"))
```

Comment: Does this https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38786 solve your problem?

Comment: Are you using tensorflow 2 or tensorflow 1?

Comment: Tensorflow 2.3.1 Kaveh

Answer (score 1):

Since you're doing this:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
```

the `tf.lite.TFLiteConverter` resolves to the TF 1.x converter API.

In general, I'd recommend to migrate everything to TF 2.x.

If it's impossible, you can try:

```
# Now `lite` is the V2 TFLite package, not `tf.compat.v1.lite`
from tensorflow import lite
converter = lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
```